# can't pass an argument of anonymous function that is passed as setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a trouble to pass a value to argument of anonymous function which is passed as an argument of setTimeout function.

I've been stuck for more than 5 hours already...

Please take a look at the code below and give me a help.

Thanks in advance!!

```
    if (_que.length > 0){

        var nextUrl = _shiftNextUrlFromQue();

        //here, the value for nextUrl exists.the value is url string.
        console.log(nextUrl); 


        setTimeout(function(nextUrl) {

            //here, the value is undefined.
            _analyzeUrl(nextUrl);


            }, 10000
        );

    }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't even need to pass it as a parameter into the function in the setTimeout... Just leave the parameter blank :)

Comment: Yes, the first parameter of the callback is `undefined` and it overrides the variable in that context.

Comment: so, you mean like this?

      setTimeout(function() {

            _analyzeUrl(nextUrl);


            }, 10000
        );

Comment: wow! I see. I'm going to try it now!

Comment: or just: setTimeout(_analyzeUrl.bind(0, nextUrl), 10000);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting *nextUrl* as an argument to the setTimeout callback function. That variable is defined in the parent function scope and there is the value you need.

The correct code would've been:

```
if (_que.length > 0) {

    var nextUrl = _shiftNextUrlFromQue();

    //here, the value for nextUrl exists.the value is url string.
    console.log(nextUrl); 


    setTimeout(function() { //HERE!... the timeout callback function has no argument

        _analyzeUrl(nextUrl);


        }, 10000
    );

}
```

Comment: OP knows they're doing that. What's the issue there?

Comment: Actually, he is *not* passing an argument. He does *expect an argument (a parameter) in the callback function* to `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass it, you're nullifying it http://jsfiddle.net/5cckcrhj/

```
setTimeout(function() {
     _analyzeUrl(nextUrl);
}, 10000
```